I completely erased the Mac OS partition, leaving Windows
I installed windows 11 on my old Macbook pro 2011 (samsung ssd 750 evo, 8 GB RAM)
At the same time, I completely erased the entire Mac OS partition, and merged it with the windows partition. Please tell me, does this action entail anything terrible? And will I be able to install Mac OS back in the future?

You will be able to reinstall macOS, but will likely need to erase the whole disk (keep backup of important Windows data) and may need to create a bootable installer (what version of macOS?).

And will I be able to make a bootable drive using the transmac high sierra program? I just want to install open core legacy patcher with macOS ventura later.

I have never used Transmac - so can't say.  Don't attempt OCLP unless you are confident of being able to fix issues.
